# Intellij not complaining about missing settings.xml in .m2 folder

Tags: java, maven

In my intellij, I have set settings.xml to the file in .m2 folder and repository to C:\repo. When i build my project, maven did not complain about missing settings.xml file in .m2 folder.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would you expect this?

Comment: A settings.xml file is not mandatory. FYI: in IntelliJ you can find your maven settings under Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven